# Jenkins on premises to Azure DevOps migration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How to migrate on premises Jenkins jobs to Azure DevOps? Is any plugins available?

I know manually how we can create Azure DevOps pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

There is some [available guidance from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/migrate/from-jenkins?view=azure-devops) on migrating from Jenkins to YAML builds in Azure Pipelines, but there are no plug-ins or tools that will automate this for you at the moment.

There is, however, a way to trigger Jenkins builds from Azure Pipelines using the [Jenkins Integration extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.services-jenkins).  This may be a good option as you transition.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no plugins available for that.